# Toggling text with jQuery without toggling all other text

Tags: jquery

Ok, so obviously I am not good at jQuery, but I know enough to know how it works. So what I need is a simple toggle, but since the text is generated by php, i need it to only toggle the text underneath that link, example:

```
<a href="#">Toggle</a>
<p class="mydesc">This text needs to be hidden until the toggle is activated.</p>
<a href="#">Toggle</a>
<p class="mydesc">This text needs to be hidden until the toggle is activated2.</p>
```

...And i will have about 20 more just like this. I know I can change .mydesc to a unique #id, but then I would have a ton of jQuery code to have toggle on each individual #id. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: do you want each `<a>` to to toggle next .mydesc p?

Comment: what exactly are you toggling? and how is the toggling being triggered? do you have any JS/jQuery written to attempt this yet? It's hard to work with such a vague question

Comment: This is what I mean, but this is for 4 of them, and I will have 25 up to maybe 50. https://jsfiddle.net/ftvaggvk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class, and just target the next element

```
<a href="#" class="myAnchor">Toggle</a>
```

then

```
$('.myAnchor').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gtmsa2ep/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using next().

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().doWhatEver();
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/ym5zqtqL/